# Проблема с формированием регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Есть большой кусок текста и в нем нужно найти слово что соответствует требованиям: только большие буквы, может содержать цифры, начинается со символов CONST, имеет длину в 21 символ. Я смог составить только следующе:

```
(CONST)+([A-Z0-9])+
```

Но оно не учитывает длины слова

Comment: вместо + попробуйте использовать {0,16}$. 16 = 21 - 5(на const)

Comment: Тогда уже не `{0,16}`, а `{16}` и после CONST не должно быть плюса

Comment: @tutankhamun насчет + после CONST согласен, а {0,16} это если менее 21 символа, этого я окончательно в вопросе не понял.

Comment: @PavelNewSky Мне кажется тут однозначно "имеет длину в 21 символ", хотя это стоит уточнить у топикстартера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(CONST)([A-Z0-9]){0,16}$` - если длина может варьироваться от 5 до 21 символов.

`(CONST)([A-Z0-9]){16}$`  - если длина ровно 21 символ.

Comment: Большое спасибо.